# Missing Category selection option for product

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products

Just adding some products a few minutes ago, and I seem to be missing the category selection option for the product.

It's just not there!  <strike>There are categories, set to display, but they don't list any products.</strike> *(categories do list products, I had a filter on for some reason!)*

When the existing products were created, they were put into various categories.

Also, the options for stock status, quantity and tax class have all disappeard too - not sure if it's related, if not I'll ask a new question for those.

Running Magento 2.1.7.  I've beens earching for a good while now, but can't find anything relevant to help (most issues involving categories are about not showing on the front end).

Cheers,

Comment: Custom module are disabled?

Comment: Cache been cleared?

Comment: All caches have been cleared mutliple times, which I understand would normally fix the frontend issue, but the back end?

Comment: There are custom modules, but they haven't been changed since it was working.

Comment: nothing in var/log or in var/report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured out what the issue was.

I had accidentally deleted the relevant attribute.  Seeing as Magento is constructed around attributes, and I guess the backend HTML template (or similar) does special things with special attributes, like the categories or the Tax Class etc.

I only figured this out accidentally when I was comparing live to demo for something else.  As such, instead of trying to figure out what else I had done, I just got the DB recreated and carried on.

This is not a real answer - perhaps Magento should have certain categories protected in some way...